# Openlayers with google map layer - points zoom before the map?

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers 2 to display a few points on a map. When I use a Google map layer and zoom in or out, the points zoom in/out before the map layer moves creating a strange effect.

```js
var google_terrain = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Terrain",
    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN}
);
```

Here is an example of the problem: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wild_kappa/rthvc2um/)

By contrast, a Bing map layer behaves as I would expect and when zooming in/out. The points and the map zoom at the same time. Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common problem happening for one using OpenLayers with Google Maps.
To resolve this issue change initialization of your map with below line.

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', { zoomMethod:null });
```

adding `zoomMethod:null` disables zoom effect applied to your feature layer.

Please refer updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nynk1tw7/1/) in which zoom is working properly.

I hope this helps you.